# Sending Mail with low level python mail api (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to embed images in email but GAE email api wont let me. So i need to use low level python api but i dont know how to authenticate with it. Is it possible? And if its possible simple example like sending text/plain email can be enough.

Thanks.

Comment: look at [smtplib.SMTP.login](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.login), but I'm not sure you can bypass GAE restrictions about sending email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAE, with  Mail API, you can embed image using `message.html` instead `message.body`.
This is the related docs [email message fields](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields)